# Null attributes in PrimeFaces dialog when saving

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The problem is with two text fields sending empty strings instead of the typed text. They're inside a dialog. The managed bean is view scoped. This command button opens the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton id="btn-open_dialog-name_query" 
                 oncomplete="PF('dialog_name_query').show();"
                 style="width: 209px; text-align: center;"
                 value="Save Query" />
```

The dialog is:

```
<p:dialog id="dlg_name_query" style="width:500px;" widgetVar="dialog_name_query" header="Save Query" hideEffect="fade" position="center center" resizable="false" showEffect="fade">
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel for="nameQuery" value="Name" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="nameQuery" value="#{dashboardDetailedMB.query.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel for="descriptionQuery" value="Description" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="descriptionQuery" value="#{dashboardDetailedMB.query.description}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id="btn-save_query-client" value="Save to current client">
                    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{dashboardDetailedMB.saveQueryClient}" update="msg" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id="btn-save_query-user" value="Save to current user">
                    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{dashboardDetailedMB.saveQueryUser}" update="msg" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Method `saveQueryClient`:

```
public void saveQueryClient() {
    try {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(false);
        String querySql = (String) session.getAttribute("querySql");
        query.setQuery(querySql);
        queryBean.add(query);
        queryBean.insertClientHasQuery(getClientId(), queryBean.getLastRow().getId());
        jsfUtils.messages("INFO", "Query inserted!", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        jsfUtils.messages("ERROR", "Error when saving query to client!", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p:commandButton` has built in ajax capabilities, so no need to use `p:ajax`. I believe your problem is that `p:ajax` defaults to `process="@this"` (which in this case only means the `commandButton`), so the `p:inputText`'s won't be submitted. But `p:commandButton` defaults to `process="@form"`, which is what you need:

```
<p:commandButton id="btn-save_query-client" 
             value="Save to current client" 
             action="#{dashboardDetailedMB.saveQueryClient}" 
             update="msg" />
```

Also it seems your form is around your dialog, I find it safest to put a form inside the dialog and put the dialog below the main form in the page, but if it works as is no need to change it.

Comment: Thanks! It also solved another issue that wasn't bothering users: double Ajax requests (maybe because of nested forms).